# Json with Swift 2, extracting data

Tags: json, xcode, swift2

I'm having this issue where I can't access values from JSON response,

the response is : {"result":[true]}

and when the JSON gets it with this code

```
            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)


                let result:String = json["result"]

                   print(result)


            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }
```

I get an error, and the when I did the debug, I saw that json had the following

[how json is stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAEx5.png)

is there anyway to access the result from json ? it didn't work treating it as an array nor as dictionary

any ideas ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is not `String`, it's an `Array` of `Bool` (represented by the brackets).

Basically **do not** annotate types unless the compiler needs them.

Cast the JSON to the proper type and use Swift native collection types. It's also recommended to use optional bindings to avoid unexpected crashes.

```
do {
     if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject],
          result = json["result"] as? [Bool] where !result.isEmpty {
        print(result[0])
     }

} catch {
     print("Error with Json: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
do{

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
            let result = json["result"] as! NSArray
               print(result)

            let boole = result[0];

        }catch {
            print("Error with Json: \(error)")
        }
```